# Cannot GET /delete/postid error node.js using hyperlink

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, get

I am using a hyperlink to delete a project that I have displayed in my main.ejs template, but when i click the delete hyperlink it displays "Cannot GET /delete/6424f79c7dd4cd07ef49acae" error. Here is the code for my hyperlink:

main.ejs:

```
<%  posts.forEach(function(post){ %>
<h3><%=post.title%></h3>
<p>
  <%=post.content.substring(0, 100) + " ..."%>
  <a href="/posts/<%=post._id%>">Read More ... </a>
  <% if (adminUser) { %>
  <a href="/delete/<%= post._id %>"method="DELETE">Delete</a>
</p>
<% } %>
<% }) %>
```

here is the get request in app.js:

```
app.get('/delete/:postid', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  const { postId } = req.params.postid;
  ProjectDetails.findByIdAndDelete({
    _id: postId,
    function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.redirect('/main');
    }
    };
  });
});
```

I have looked for solutions but alot of them seem to involve restful apis which is something I'm not familiar with. Is there another way to fix?

Answer (score 0):

The first line inside the function is wrong. Use

```
const { postId } = req.params
```

or

```
const postId = req.params.postId
```

The reason, why you get the timeout on the request, is that you are not sending a reply at all in [any error case](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#writing-error-handlers).

If you are not sending a reply, the client will end up in a timeout error while requesting `GET /...`.

You should always send a reply, even in the error case, so just log the error of the node application and redirect the client to `/main` anyway.

```js
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    res.redirect('/main');
```

Comment: thanks for the help! After editing my code the page just buffers? when I hit refresh the project is still displaying on the page.

Comment: That depends on how you deliver the page. You need to send the [respective headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#use_cases) at your `/main` path. In express this could be done with `res.header("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); res.send(content);` for example.